# Failed to install msvc 2012 express on windows x64 using ISO image, log install attached

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

It's was confusing to have msvc 2012 express error install in my laptop.. I've only MSE(Microsoft Security Essential) activated antivir, and none auto startup annoying program like  java updater etc.. 
here is my install log at http://pastebin.com/86CCBdJt

I just want use google-breakpad crash reporting, since it doesnt really support for mingw. But appearently there would be someone had a patch (found googling), Didnt know will work or not, so I decide to use msvc backend instead..

I hope any one had using msvc 2012 could have solving my problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you will look at string : 
[0440:0E3C][2014-03-24T08:40:00]: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_minshellcore) failed: Error Message Id: 1304 ErrorMessage: Error writing to file: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory.

It saying, that installtion cant access some folder, you must try it install as Administrator.

Comment: emh, very long answer. btw my problem had already solved sometime ago..:)